# Why does "Den Prognosen [zufolge/gemäß] versagte Windows 2000" have to use entsprechend

Tags: word-usage

According to [this site](http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Praepositionen/Prepositions2.html#zufolge)

> Den Prognosen zufolge/gemäß versagte Windows 2000
>
> <strike>As predicted [in accordance with predictions], Windows 2000 failed.</strike> 
>   [You would need to use entsprechend here.]

only *entsprechend* is appropriate here. But there is no explanation. Why is only *entsprechend* correct?

Comment: Note on the translation of failed: if we are talking about a commercial failure (which I suspect is what is meant) then "verkaufte sich schlecht" would be more appropriate. The verb "versagen" would mean to fail in a technical sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's actually correct, although probably many people would do it wrong and not even notice. The reason is (suposedly) that "Den Prognosen zufolge" works only if the stated result has not happened yet, meaning the fact is in the future:

> Den Prognosen zufolge regnet es morgen.

but:

> Entsprechend den Prognosen regnet es heute.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the difference between *zufolge* and *entsprechend* is quite subtle and what makes this sentence sound so weird/wrong with *zufolge* is the future oriented nature of *Prognose*.

For example the sentence:

*Den Gerüchten zufolge versagte Windows 2000 aufgrund von [...]*

sounds perfectly natural. [You'll find a similar example on duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zufolge)

*Prognosen* concern something in the future and in your particular example the prognosed event has already happended. So *entsprechend* is correct. It's equivalent to "as predicted". *Zufolge* is more like *according to*.

Compare these sentences:

*According to the prognoses Windows 2000 failed.*

and

*According to statistics/rumours Windows 2000 failed.*

*Gemäß* sounds weird in either case. As a native speaker I'm not sure if it's strictly wrong, but it would earn you a couple of weird looks. 
*Gemäß* is usually used in association with texts of law.

Example: 
*Gemäß § 2 BGB tritt die Volljährigkeit mit Vollendung des 18. Lebensjahres ein.*